# Creating document in Postscript format with C#

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, postscript

Is there an API available to write directly to postscript format with C#? I am currently using pdfnet to write a document to pdf and then use adobe to export that to postscript. However, quality is being lost during the conversion and I need to go directly to postscript and skip creating the pdf.

The document contains an image with some text overlayed on top of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try different solutions to convert the PDF.  [Ghostscript](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/), for example, will allow you to specify resolution etc.  Also, if the final destination is print, may printers now support direct PDF printing which might help solve the issue.

Comment: I had thought about going down this route and it will probably be what I end up doing. The final product is actually PDF, but the client requires that I sent the postscript file through Distiller to create the PDF. I'm not sure of the technical reasons for this, but the client says this is what the printshop requires.

Comment: You could try sending a file to the printshop to see if they can process it.  It might solve all of your problems.

Answer (score 3):

You know how to use files in C#, right?  A very simple way to do it would be to just have your program create a new `ofstream` or whatever C# calls it, naming it whatever.ps, and just appending strings to the file.  Its really quite easy to learn, although I'd recommend actually getting a print copy of the Postscript Language Reference manual if you are going to do it that way.  Even though you can get an electronic version for free, it really isn't as useful as a print copy unless you have more than one monitor.

For instance, to draw a 1" square centered at the middle of a portrait-oriented piece of letter-size paper in C++, I'd do something like:

```
myFile << "%!PS-Adobe-2.0 \n" //header block
       << "%%Creator: INSERT YOUR NAME HERE \n"
       << "%%Title: FILENAME.ps \n"
       << "%%Pages: 1 \n"
       << "%%PageOrder: Ascend \n"
       << "%%BoundingBox: 0 0 612 792 \n"
       << "%%DocumentPaperSizes: Letter \n"
       << "%%EndComments \n"

myFile << "<< /PageSize [612 792] >> setpagedevice \n" //page setup
       << "396 306 translate \n" //set (0,0) to center of page

myFile << "-36 -36 72 72 rectfill \n" //the rectangle at last!
```

You would need to translate that into whatever language you are using, though.  Also, to be more readable, you might put the header block into its own function.  In fact, you don't even need the newlines at the end of each string, except in the header block.

Comment: Terrible answer, first off extremely condescending, second is that answer has no relevance to question, furthermore attempts to answer it using a different language then that specified by the question.

Comment: Ironically, this is one of the most sensible answers I've seen on the subject.  Postscript is a very specific language, and the idea of writing to some kind of API just to have it turn around and spit out Postscript is "almost" pointless.  If you want postscript output and don't want a conversion from some graphics format you already have, then you may need to generate postscript directly.   http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/postscript/
However, the benefit of an API would be that you could invoke language functions without looking up PS equivalent, but I haven't seen such an API anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Cairo Graphics - http://www.cairographics.org/ seems like a possible option. It has bindings to C#/.NET and MONO.

Comment: I had seen this but it looks like it has some limitations on fonts. I use some custom fonts and with Cairo it looked like I need to implement some additional libraries to work with non-standard fonts.

Comment: If you don't mind c then http://pslib.sourceforge.net/ could be useful.  Unfortunately no bindings for c#.  Also http://www.unifont.org/lasi/ - more font support but c++ only.